# Pycharm warning - 'Relative import outside of a package'

Tags: python, pycharm

Here's the working folder structure

```
foo/
├─ foo/
│  ├─ __init__.py
__main__.py
```

Here's what `__main__.py` looks like:

```py
from .foo import bar

bar()
```

Here's what the `__init__.py` looks like:

```py
def bar():
    print("hello")
    pass
```

When I do `python -m foo` from outside root, it works as expected. However, PyCharm complains about the `from .foo import bar` line. The warning message is:

> Relative import outside of a package

If the problematic line is changed to `from foo import bar`, PyCharm doesn't complain but I get following error when running `python -m foo`:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'bar' from 'foo' (unknown location)

Is there a way to have it work while resolving PyCharm warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to get rid of the warnings by turning the top-level `foo` directory into its own package.

Adding an `__init__.py` to top-level `foo` directory might get the job done.